# Maximum Throughput of a grid of hardware logic operations

Tags: hardware, cpu-architecture

Given this System, and assuming we pipelined it with the minimum number of registers:

[image: Click me for the picture]

How can I calculate the maximum throughput without even knowing the minimum number of registers needed to pipeline this?

Comment: `C` looks like an obvious bottleneck.  The total throughput is going to be something like one result from C per clock.  If C can't be internally pipelined, then its propagation delay of 25ns is going to be the bottleneck for high you can clock the system, right?  It should be possible to pipeline the rest of it to have input for C ready that often, since the other stages have shorter propagation delays.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you! It really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C` looks like an obvious bottleneck.  The total throughput is going to be something like one result from `C` per clock. If `C` can't be internally pipelined, then its propagation delay of 25ns is going to be the bottleneck for how high you can clock the system, right?

It should be possible to pipeline the rest of it to have input for C ready that often, since the other stages have shorter propagation delays.